# Multidimensional array prints hexadecimal numbers instead of the contents of the array. Why?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, printing, hex

```
...C++.....................
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int troysArray[3][3] = {
    {3,2,7},
    {4,5,8},
    {1,9,2},
};

int i;
int j;

for (i = 0;i < 3;i++)
    for (j = 0;j < 3;j++){

    cout << troysArray[i] << endl;
    cout << troysArray[j] << endl;
};

return 0;
}
.......................
C++
```

> > Why does the above code print out hex numbers when I'm actually trying to print out the contents of the array. (Beginner/Just practicing)
> >
> > What am I doing wrong that's causing this to occur?

Comment: Include the output in the question.

Comment: `troysArray[i]` --> `troysArray[i][j]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print out the contents of the table in a grid (as asked in one of the comments on Guarev Senghai's answer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int troysArray[3][3] = {
    {3,2,7},
    {4,5,8},
    {1,9,2},
};

int i;
int j;

for (i = 0;i < 3;i++)
{
    for (j = 0;j < 3;j++)
    {
        cout << troysArray[i][j];  

        //uncomment the next line to have a spaces between the numbers.
        cout << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Spoonless, the above code came closer, but this is what happened: 327458192.  Is there a way to print it as the following: 327 endl 458 endl 192 endl ??

Comment: Yes just take the last bit out of the first cout

Comment: I changed the code to make it more obvious how to not print  spaces between the numbers

Comment: @user9954181 You're welcome. If it solved your problem, please mark it is as the accepted answer to help other people with similar problems find it in future

Answer (score 3):

The best overload of the `std::ostream` `<<` operator for `troysArray[i]` is `void*` (exploiting *pointer decay*), and that outputs the *address* of the pointer.

If you want an *element* use `troysArray[i][j]` &c.

Answer (score 1):

`troysArray[i]` and `troysArray[j]` are pointers to an array. If you want to print element at `i` and `j`, use

```
cout << troysArray[i][j] << endl;
```

Comment: Didnt you want `cout << troysArray[i][j] << endl;` ?

Comment: Thank you.  Your suggestions worked to get it to stop printing in hex, but it's printing the elements of the array in a vertical line.  How do I get it to print in a table-like fashion? Or alternatively, to include the indices of each element first?

Answer (score 1):

`troysArray` is an array of arrays of `int`.
Thus, `troysArray[i]` is an array of `int`, and so is `troysArray[j]`.

There is no overload of `operator <<` for array of `int`.
However, there is one for `void*`.

When you pass an array as an argument, what actually gets passed is a pointer to the array's first element.
(In your case, those are `&troysArray[i][0]` and `&troysArray[j][0]`, both of type `int*`.)

An `int*` can be implicitly converted to `void*`, so the `operator <<` for `void*` can be used.

This overload outputs the value of the pointer in hexadecimal form.

In order to print the `int`s you need to print the elements `j` of each array `troysArray[i]`:

```
cout << troysArray[i][j] << endl;
```

To print it more "matrix-like", with each row on its own line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        cout << troysArray[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```